# jQuery is undefined jquery-ui-1.9.2 and jquery-migrate-1.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to fix the mobile version of my website and I was doing pretty good so far, but I run into some errors in the google chrome console, 4 errors to be more accurate and because of them, some links on the page wont open when clicked on, they just make an weird animation and won't open.

The website wasn't made by me, I just got it from a friend and I'm struggling to fix his bugs and make it work.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:511

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js:351

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js:6
```

It's a weird error, I really don't get it.

Comment: You most probably do not include jquery itself *before* the other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend not modifying jQuery scripts. I'd get the most recent jQuery files from [the jQuery code site](http://code.jquery.com/).
The custom scripts might have faults in them so the "normal" code can't work.

Did you already click on the line number? It will show you where the error is.

Comment: What makes you think he uses modified jQuery files? I bet it's just the wrong order.

Comment: Yes, I've pressed it takes me to that line of code,  `})( jQuery );`

Comment: @Robert one file's called xy. **custom** .js..
I'd try getting new, fresh files.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a great idea, where can I get the jQuerry-ui ?
Is it hosted somewhere on the web so I can, just add it via <script> tag?
I've found jquery-migrate and added it, some errors dissapeared,I just need the jquery-ui and I think it should work.

Comment: @AlexandruIanas Same site, scroll a bit down. ;) Direct link to all versions: http://code.jquery.com/ui/

Comment: Thanks guys, I added this script [link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js), it works like a charm.

Comment: @Sandesire: You're right, of course... didn't see that!